# How to compress csv file into zip archive directly?

Tags: python, csv, gzip, zip

I am generating a number of csv files dynamically, using the following code:

```
import csv
fieldnames = ['foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3', 'foo4']
with open(csvfilepath, 'wb') as csvfile:
    csvwrite = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldnames)
    csvwrite.writeheader()
    for row in data:
        csvwrite.writerow(row)
```

To save space, I want to compress them.
Using the `gzip` module is quite easy:

```
with gzip.open("foo.gz", "w") as csvfile :
    csvwrite = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldnames)
    csvwrite.writeheader()
    for row in data:
        csvwrite.writerow(row)
```

But I want the file in 'zip' format.

I tried the `zipfile` module, but I am unable to directly write files into the zip archive.

Instead, I have to write the csv file to disk, compress them in a zip file using following code, and then delete the csv file.

```
with ZipFile(zipfilepath, 'w') as zipfile:
    zipfile.write(csvfilepath, csvfilename, ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

How can I write a csv file directly to a compressed zip similar to gzip?

Comment: wow using gzip is so easy! On Py3 I had to use this to convert the strings to bytes though, before being able to start a `csv.writer` and write lines out `csv_out_file = io.TextIOWrapper(outfile, encoding='utf-8', newline='', write_through=True)`

Answer (score 16):

Use the [`cStringIO.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) object to imitate a file:

```
with ZipFile(your_zip_file, 'w', ZIP_DEFLATED) as zip_file:
    string_buffer = StringIO()
    writer = csv.writer(string_buffer)

    # Write data using the writer object.

    zip_file.writestr(filename + '.csv', string_buffer.getvalue())
```

Comment: cool. thanks for quick answer. it's done with little modification. Please check my answer.

Comment: In Python 3, this has moved to [io.StringIO](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/io.html#io.StringIO).

Answer (score 4):

Thanks kroolik
It's done with little modification.

```
with ZipFile(your_zip_file, 'w', ZIP_DEFLATED) as zip_file:
    string_buffer = StringIO()
    csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(string_buffer, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldnames)
    csvwrite.writeheader()
    for row in cdrdata:
        csvwrite.writerow(row)
    zip_file.writestr(filename + '.csv', string_buffer.getvalue())
```

Comment: note: `StringIO()` accumulates the data in memory.  It is not very suitable if uncompressed data can't fit in memory.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian thnks for comment. Can you suggest any better alternative?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thanks but I am using 'zip' format because I am planning to use this file on windows. Is there any commonly used format for windows like zip?

Comment: I know that `7z` works on Windows too and it supports many formats.

Answer (score 0):

Having IOString to store every bytes in memory could be very memory consuming.

Based on the [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile-objects) module documentation after creating a `ZipFile` object, all individual files has to be opened. Like this:

```
with ZipFile('spam.zip') as myzip:
    with myzip.open('eggs.txt') as myfile:
        print(myfile.read())
```

This example can be used for `write` as well...