# How to reduce the size of a txt file created by Python?

Tags: python, pandas, io, pyodbc, netezza

I have about 2M rows x 70 columns worth of numerical and categorical data in a table on a Netezza server and want to dump that into a .txt file using Python.
I have done this in the past with SAS and on my test case I get a txt file worth 450MB.
I used Python and tried a couple of things.

```
# One line at a time

startTime = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=NZ_LAB')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
c = cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM MYTABLE""")

with open('dump_test_pyodbc.csv','wb') as csv:
    csv.write(','.join([g[0] for g in c.description])+'\n')
    while 1:
        a=c.fetchone()
        if not a:
            break
        csv.write(','.join([str(g) for g in a])+'\n')
cnxn.close()

endTime = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
print "Time elapsed PYODBC:", endTime - startTime

>>Time elapsed PYODBC: 0:18:20



# Use Pandas chunksize
startTime = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=NZ_LAB')

sql = ("""SELECT * FROM MYTABLE""")

df = psql.read_sql(sql, cnxn, chunksize=1000)

for k, chunk in enumerate(df):
    if k == 0:
        chunk.to_csv('dump_chunk.csv',index=False,mode='w')
    else:
        chunk.to_csv('dump_chunk.csv',index=False,mode='a',header=False)

endTime = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
print "Time elapsed PANDAS:", endTime - startTime
cnxn.close()

>>Time elapsed PANDAS: 0:29:29
```

Now to the size:
The Pandas approach created a file worth 690MB, the other approach created a file worth 630MB.
Speed and size seem to favor the former approach, however, size wise, this is still much larger than the original SAS approach.
Any ideas on how to improve the Python approach(es) to reduce the output size?

EDIT: ADDING EXAMPLES--------------------

Ok, it seems like SAS is doing a better job at managing integers, where it makes sense. I think that's what is making up most of the difference in size.

SAS:
xxxxxx,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2.49,40.65,63.31,1249.92...

Pandas:
xxxxxx,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.49,40.65,63.31,1249.92...

fetchone():
xxxxxx,0.00,0.00,0,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,2.49,40.65,63.31,1249.92...

EDIT 2: SOLUTION------------------------------------

I ended up removing unnecessary decimals with:

```
csv.write(','.join([str(g.strip()) if type(g)==str else '%g'%(g) for g in a])+'\n')
```

This brought the file size down to SAS level.

Comment: it seems you need all the descriptions which account for the size.  Can you not compress after the fact?

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Do you consider compressing approaches? For example you could use one of the following compression: [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/archiving.html)

Comment: What about this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25971205/how-to-compress-csv-file-into-zip-archive-directly

Comment: Ok, just to clarify: for the time being, I'm trying to figure out if there are ways to reduce the file size without using compression.

Comment: I mean, zip "yourfile.txt" and call it a day.  Unless you want your own compression technique.

Comment: You are asking how to make any txt file smaller without compression (has nothing to do with python).  Making it smaller IS compression.  Fully expanded is what you have, so the answer is no.

Comment: Care to let us know what it is that actually makes the sizes differ? Is it some whitespace padding, is it some floatingpoint numbers not being rounded appropriately, or something else? Can you post the different length versions of a representative record?

Comment: Hanno, that is what I do not know. Let me take a closer look and will post an example.

Comment: But I am guessing your question is really how to significantly reduce the file size.  Playing with spacing isn't going to buy you much in the long run, it's still going to take  X minutes to transfer.

Comment: ergonaut, my question (sorry if it wasn't clear) was about the significant difference between the SAS exported file and the Python files. I was wondering if there is something I could do on the Python side to keep files in the same range as the SAS file.

Comment: Can you post SAS code in support of @FlipperPA answer below? Thanks

Comment: My bet is on floating point and/or date/time fields being formatted differently on output. "1.50" vs. "1.5000000000001" or "2015-09-23" vs. "2015-09-23 00:00:00.000 AM" &c.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to make this a comment, but text formatting will help.

My guess is you're running into an issue of quoted vs unquoted CSV files. SAS has an option to create unquoted CSV files. Here's an example:

```
This Value,That Value,3,Other Value,423,985.32
```

The file I think you're getting is more accurate, and won't create problems for fields with commas in them. The same row, quoted:

```
"This Value","That Value","3","Other Value","423,985.32"
```

As you can see, in the first (SAS) example, if read into a Spreadsheet it would read as two different values, "423" and "985.32". In the second example, it becomes clear it is actually one value, "423,985.32". This is why the quoted format you are now getting (if I'm right) is more accurate and safe.

Comment: Actually writing a CSV file in SAS will normally only add the quotes around fields that require them. So in your example only the last field would have quotes since the value contains the delimiter.  If Python is adding quotes around all values (or even just all character values) then that could explain why the SAS generated file is slightly smaller.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification Tom, my SAS knowledge is thimble sized. :)