# Zip a csv file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, compression, gzip

I'm trying to zip a csv file using gzip but getting an empty path returned to a variable.

```
zip_file = subprocess.check_output(["gzip", "-f", file_name])
print zip_file
```

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25971309/6505847)

Answer (score 0):

If you call `gzip -f foo`, then the executable `gzip` will read the file `foo` and create a new file called `foo.gz`.  It will output nothing to stdout, so the return value of `subprocess.check_output()` will be an empty string (or bytes object in Python3).

`gzip` behaves differently if it reads from stdin, then it will also write to stdout.  You can force this behavior also with a file as input, by giving the option `-c`:

```
b = subprocess.check_output([ 'gzip', '-c', file_name ])
```

After this, `b` will contain the bytes `gzip` is produced.