# How to write CSV file to zip on the fly

Tags: python, django, csv, zip

```
  def download_csv(self, prepared_data):
        file_name = self.get_file_name(self.request.query_params.get('model'), 'csv')
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(file_name)

        writer = csv.writer(response)
        writer.writerow(prepared_data.get('labels'))
        for data in prepared_data.get('data'):
            writer.writerow(data)

        return response
```

This is the original code for extracting data from the website in CSV format.

Now I need to add some limitations and if the limit is exceeded create a zip file containing CSV files. For example, if the limit is 10 and I have 23 rows of data, a zip file will contain 3 CSV files.

I am trying to implement this code:

```
def download_csv(self, prepared_data):
    file_name = self.get_file_name(self.request.query_params.get('model'), 'csv')
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(file_name)
    from io import StringIO
    limit = 2
    if len(prepared_data.get('data')) > limit:
        temp_file = StringIO()
        comp_file = zipfile.ZipFile(temp_file, 'w')
        for _ in range(int(len(prepared_data.get('data'))/limit)):
            writer = csv.writer(response)
            writer.writerow(prepared_data.get('labels'))
            for data in prepared_data.get('data'):
                writer.writerow(data)
            comp_file.writestr(data=writer, compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
        comp_file.close()

    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(prepared_data.get('labels'))
    for data in prepared_data.get('data'):
        writer.writerow(data)

    return response
```

but it fails with the error `"path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not _csv.writer"`

All I need to accomplish is, to get CSV files to write to zipfile. I'd be sincerely grateful for any help or hint. Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25971205/how-to-compress-csv-file-into-zip-archive-directly) thread.

Comment: can you please add the full stacktrace?

Answer (score -2):

Your code has errors all over it.

The first I can see is that you imported StringIO but didn't provide an argument when calling the function for temp_file:

```
from io import StringIO
temp_file = StringIO(PROVIDE_ARGUMENT_HERE)
```

Providing the argument should get you on the path to solving this.